# Salesforce Login Authentication for External Website

Tags: authentication, salesforce

We have an external application which we would like to authenticate using salesforce.com. I have read salesforce.com documentation for using OAuth but i am not clear how to implement this feature (We do not want Client to manually go and create Client key). Basically we want someone to access our system but login authentication will be verified by salesforce. Imagine a website which authenticates by using Salesforce.com credentials. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You would setup like any other OAuth external app.  Once you get an OAuth token from Salesforce, you will also receive user identifiers in the same data package.  You can then do what you want with this identifier.

See [this doc](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_streaming/Content/code_sample_auth_oauth.htm) for how to setup OAuth2 authentication.

Note:  The client id needs to be created, but only ONCE.  It can be created on a developer org, and does not need to be created on every client org.